# DropDownListFor not trasfering data to controller

Tags: dropdownlistfor

I am beginner in MVC. If someone could help me, please!

I have following in my view

```
<div class="form_group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Time)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Genre, new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Type"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })

    </div>
```

And I have following view model

```
public class GigsFormViewModel
    {
        public string Venue { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; } 
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
        public int Genre;
    }
```

When I press the submit button I am not getting the selected id of Genre in the controller ( ie GigsFormViewModel.Genre is always 0 )

However Date, time and Venue are getting populated.

Following is the look of my controller.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(GigsFormViewModel gvm)
        { 
             var venue = gvm.Venue ;//This got entered value
             int genre = gvm.Genre ; //This is always 0
    }
```

What am I missing? 
I am grateful for trying to help me.

thanks
Gulumal.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GigsFormViewModel
    {
        public string Venue { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; } 
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
        *public int Genre{ get; set; }*
    }
```

I need to make Genre a property!